# Where can I find the cost of commodities in different markets?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, economic-history, data, imf

Where can I find a database that tracks current and historic prices of different products and services in regions around the world?

I'm very sure that some organizations track the cost of common commodities for different markets globally, and they make this database publicly available for lenders, researchers, etc.

For example:

- Price for one 25-kg bag of wheat flour,
- Price for 1 pair of shoes,
- Price for 1-month of rent,
- Price for 3-meters of 10 mm rebar,
- Price for 25-kg sack of cement,
- Price for 1-hour of lawyer fees,
- etc

Unfortunately, I couldn't find them with a search engine.

What websites can I visit to query the current & historical cost of commodities globally?

Comment: These aren't commodities. Commodities are raw materials used to create products. No one trades pairs of shoes or 25kg wheat flower. You can look at retail price comparison sites like [Skinflint](https://skinflint.co.uk/oral-b-io-series-6-pink-a2640261.html).

Comment: Some of these aren't very fungible either; the price of a pair of shoes can vary wildly depending on the exact shoes you choose. The same goes for rent, lawyers, etc. As a result, there will not be *a* price for these.